# What is the best model to use with a time-series dataset of uneven data?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, predictive-models, lstm

I'm working on building/selecting a model to predict the result of a sales lead: whether it's "SOLD" or "NOT SOLD".

My dataset consists of past leads with the following data:

- sales rep
- product pitched
- lead source
- date of lead
- zipcode
- result

The issue I'm running into is that I have a various amount of leads per day per rep. Here is some sample data:

| ID | salesrep | product | leadsource | date | zipcode | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | A | Website | 5-1-2023 | 12345 | SOLD |
| 2 | Bob | A | Call In | 5-1-2023 | 12344 | NOT SOLD |
| 3 | Alice | A | Website | 5-1-2023 | 12343 | NOT SOLD |
| 4 | Bob | A | Referral | 5-1-2023 | 12346 | NOT SOLD |
| 5 | Alice | A | Call In | 5-2-2023 | 12345 | SOLD |
| 6 | Bob | B | Referral | 5-2-2023 | 12344 | SOLD |
| 7 | Alice | B | Website | 5-2-2023 | 12342 | NOT SOLD |
| 8 | Alice | A | Call In | 5-3-2023 | 12333 | SOLD |

In this example, I have three dates of data.

- Day 1 (5-1-2023) has Bob with 3 leads, and Alice with 1.
- Day 2 (5-2-2023) has Bob with 1 lead and Alice with 2 leads.
- Day 3 (5-3-2023) has just Alice with 1 lead.

Now let's say I have information for a lead for day 4:

| ID | salesrep | product | leadsource | date | zipcode | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | Bob | A | Website | 5-4-2023 | 12345 | ??? |

I want to predict the result - specifically, the probability of the result being "SOLD".

Initially I was thinking about using something like a Decision Tree/Random Forest/XG Boost classifier, but realized that this data may have a time-series aspect to it.  The business is seasonal and has a "busy season" during the spring and summer months, and I'd also like to account for sales reps that are on "hot streaks".

For this I was thinking about making use of an LSTM RNN model, but I'm not sure if my data's "shape" is appropriate for this model type, as I have a various amount of data points per date, some dates have no data points for specific reps, and some dates have no data points at all (no leads on Sundays, federal holidays, etc).

Thoughts on this?  Which model would you use in this scenario?